# vba: getElementsByClassName with different class names

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I am working on an excel sheet, which collects data from a website. A few words about this website:
- it is independant from me, I can not change its struckture
- it should look like a table, but it is not. The structure is like this:

```
<h4>blabla</h4><span class="address">blabla</span><span class="state_x">blabla</span>
<h4>blabla</h4><span class="address">blabla</span><span class="state_x">blabla</span>
<h4>blabla</h4><span class="address">blabla</span><span class="state_y">blabla</span>
```

The trick is the "state_?" class, its name can change (but only the end of it).

What am I doing now?
- collect all the data into arrays
- of course I will get "state_x" and "state_y" arrays
- go through the arrays, and write everything to a sheet

The problem:
When I get to the "state_?" arrays, I already don't know, where its data came from. 
The best would be to have only one "state" array, which can collect data from any "state_?" classes. Of course this code doesn't work, but to show the logic:

```
Dim state As Variant
Set state = ieApp.Document.getElementsByClassName("state_*")
```

How could this work? Any help is appreciated, please consider, that I am new in vba.

NEW INFOS

I have found some further help by analysing the source HTML code. Each row is nested in a `<div class="listitem"> </div>`. Is it possible to create an array, where each element is a complete "listitem" div, and with a for loop extract the data from these elements, as written above?
Each "listitem" div can contain only one "state_?" class. So this way I wouldn't loose the information, where the data comes from.

Comment: Try getElementsByTagName of span or h and then look at the className of that object via a loop through the collection returned from getElementsByTagName

Answer (score 0):

Try `querySelectorAll` with selector e.g. `"*[class^='state_']"` which should select all elements which have class name that starts with text `state_`. More about selectors [here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp). HTH

```
Dim states As IHTMLDOMChildrenCollection
Set doc = ie.document
Set states = doc.querySelectorAll("*[class^='state_']")

If (Not states Is Nothing) Then
   Dim i
   For i = 0 To states.Length - 1
    Debug.Print states(i).innerHTML
   Next i
End If
```

Comment: I keep reading and trying, actually I like the idea of selectors. But as I am using querySelectorAll (even with simple selector) or getElementsByClassName with any kind of complex selector, the "states" array remains empty.

Comment: And are you sure, those elements are really loaded and part of the DOM at the time when you execute the VBA code?

Comment: If I run this: `Dim state1 As Variant
Set state1 = ieApp.Document.getElementsByClassName("state_x") Dim state2 As Variant
'Set state2 = ieApp.Document.getElementsByClassName("state_y")` it collects all the data. But into two arrays...

Comment: See edited answer, i have made a mistake before. This code works for me with the html example you provided in the question.

Comment: Thanks for the correction! I saw this mistype, and tested the correct version before. Still nothing. <br>
Can there be version problem? My IE is new (11), the vba is 7.1, the Excel 2013

Comment: OK. No I do not think there is version problem. Try to experiment with the method `querySelectorAl`. In case this does not work you could create some `Merge` function by yourself? E.g. like `Function Merge(state1 As IHTMLElementCollection, state2 As IHTMLElementCollection) As VBA.Collection`.

Comment: I was thinking about that, but there is a problem. When I create the two (or actually four - doesn't matter) arrays, I already loose the information, which data came from which row. I keep trying with the selectors, that must be the solution.